# passing dynamic value from onclick to another javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to pass dynamically generated value through the below javascript onclick event to other javascript function. Code is below:

```
      var data = function(value, rowIndex) {
                var Id = this.grid.getItem(rowIndex).ID;
                //alert("ID+ " + Id);
                return  "<img src=../img/normal.jpg width=\"20\" height=\"20\" onClick=\"show(Id)\">";
            };
show(id){
alert(id);//unable to get id value here from the above onclick event.can't we pass dynamic value as shown above.
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement should look like this instead:

```
return  "<img src=../img/normal.jpg width=\"20\" height=\"20\" onClick=\"show(" + Id + ")\">";
```